# Accuracy problems in overdefined linear system

Tags: python, linear-algebra, floating-accuracy

#### Background

For a given list of points, I want to check whether they lie in the interior of a (possibly lower dimensional) simplex.
I want to do this in Python.

### Problem

**Edit:** At its heart, I want to (repeatedly) answer the question, whether `u` lies in the image of `A` (as decision problem, so just yes/no).

First I do QR-factorisation and then solve the system and finally check, whether the solution is correct.

```
import scipy.linalg
import numpy as np

Q,R = np.linalg.qr(AA)
for u in points:
  x = scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(R, np.dot(Q.T, u))
  print(all(x <= 1-1e-6) and all(x >= 1e-6) and all(abs(np.dot(AA,x) - u) < 1e-6))
```

However, I ran into numerical problems, that the accuracy seems to be too bad. I have a point, which lies inside (according to previous computation with linear programme), but the above code fails to recognise this.

The condition of the matrix is about 100, the shape is `(36,35)`, so it seems not that terrible, but the error lies slightly above `1e-6`

Is there some way to improve the accuracy?

- I tried it symbolic with `sympy`, but had to interrupt the computation. Took way too long.
- I prefer not to increase the threshold `1e-6` any further.
- Since the system is overdefined (i.e. the simplex has lower dimension), I need that last check, whether my solution is correct.

#### Data

```
AA = np.array([
[1,  1,  1, 1,  1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1,  1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
[0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 0,  2, 2, 2,  2,  2,  4,  4,  6,  6, 6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  8],
[0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 2,  2, 2,  2, 4, 6,  0, 0, 0,  4,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  6],
[0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 2, 4, 0,  0, 0,  4, 4, 4,  0, 0, 4,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  2,  2,  6,  0,  0],
[0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 2,  2,  2,  4,  4, 6,  6, 0, 0, 0,  0, 2,  0, 0, 0,  0, 2, 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0, 6,  0,  2,  4,  0,  4],
[0,  0,  0, 4, 10, 0,  0,  6,  0,  0, 2,  2, 2, 0, 2,  2, 4,  2, 2, 0,  0, 2, 4,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4, 6,  2,  0,  2,  0,  0],
[0,  2,  2, 0,  4, 4,  4,  2,  2,  4, 2,  4, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2,  0, 0, 0,  0, 6, 2,  2,  0,  4,  0,  4,  0, 0,  0,  2,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  0,  2, 0,  4, 0,  2,  6,  0,  0, 0,  0, 6, 2, 0,  0, 0,  4, 6, 6,  6, 0, 4,  4,  0,  2,  6,  8,  0, 0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0],
[0,  0,  0, 0,  6, 8,  0,  0,  2,  0, 2,  4, 2, 6, 2,  4, 2,  0, 0, 2,  2, 0, 0,  2,  4,  0,  0,  2,  4, 2, 10,  2,  0, 12,  0],
[0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 2,  0,  6,  2,  2, 0,  0, 2, 4, 0,  0, 0,  2, 0, 2,  2, 4, 0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0],
[0,  2,  0, 0,  2, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 4,  4, 0, 0, 0,  4, 2,  4, 8, 0,  0, 2, 2,  0,  0,  6,  0,  4,  0, 0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0,  0,  2, 6,  4, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 8,  0, 6, 0, 4, 10, 0,  2, 0, 0,  4, 2, 6,  2,  2,  0,  2,  0,  0, 8,  2,  0,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  0,  2, 0,  4, 8,  2, 14,  0,  0, 6,  0, 0, 0, 4,  8, 0,  4, 2, 4,  0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  2,  8,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  2],
[0,  0,  6, 6,  0, 0,  0,  0,  4,  0, 0,  0, 0, 4, 4,  0, 0,  2, 0, 0,  2, 2, 2,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0, 8,  0,  4,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  6,  0, 2,  0, 2,  0,  2,  0,  0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0,  0, 4,  0, 0, 2,  0, 0, 0,  2,  0,  2,  0,  2,  2, 2,  2,  4,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  0,  0, 6,  0, 0,  8,  0,  0,  0, 8,  0, 8, 0, 0,  0, 2,  4, 0, 0,  2, 0, 0,  0,  2,  0,  4,  0,  0, 2,  0, 10,  8,  0,  2],
[0,  2,  2, 0,  0, 0,  2,  0,  2,  2, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  2, 0,  0, 2, 0,  2, 0, 2,  6,  2,  0,  0,  2,  6, 2,  4,  0,  4,  0,  2],
[0, 10,  0, 0,  0, 2,  2,  4,  0,  2, 0,  0, 0, 8, 0,  6, 6,  4, 0, 4,  2, 2, 0,  2,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0, 2,  0,  0,  4,  0, 10],
[0,  4,  0, 0,  4, 2,  0,  0,  0,  0, 2,  2, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0,  0, 4, 4,  0, 8, 2, 12,  4,  8,  0,  0,  4, 0,  6,  2, 10,  0,  2],
[0,  0,  4, 8,  6, 2,  0,  0, 12,  0, 2,  2, 0, 0, 0,  0, 2,  4, 0, 2,  0, 2, 0,  2,  4,  0,  2,  2, 10, 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  2],
[0,  2,  2, 2,  2, 0,  0,  0,  2,  0, 0,  0, 6, 6, 2,  0, 2,  2, 4, 2,  4, 4, 4,  2, 10,  6,  2,  0,  2, 0,  0,  0,  2,  2,  8],
[0,  4,  0, 4,  0, 0,  0,  0,  2, 16, 0,  2, 0, 0, 6,  0, 4,  0, 0, 4,  0, 2, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0,  2,  2,  0,  0, 2,  0, 6, 0, 0,  0, 2,  0, 0, 0,  2, 0, 4,  0,  2,  4,  2,  2,  2, 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  0,  4, 6,  6, 2,  8,  0,  4,  0, 0,  2, 0, 2, 0,  2, 4,  2, 0, 0,  2, 2, 0,  6,  2, 12,  4,  0,  0, 0,  4,  0,  0,  4,  2],
[0,  0,  4, 0,  0, 0,  0,  2,  4,  2, 2,  0, 0, 0, 2,  2, 4,  4, 4, 4,  2, 4, 4,  0,  2,  0,  0,  6,  2, 2,  2,  6,  0,  0,  2],
[0,  0,  2, 0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 10, 2, 0, 8,  2, 4,  0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  4,  2, 2,  0,  0,  2,  0,  2],
[0,  2,  0, 0,  0, 8,  4,  2,  4,  6, 0,  0, 0, 2, 0,  0, 2,  0, 8, 0,  0, 0, 0,  0,  2,  0,  2,  0, 12, 4,  0,  0,  2,  0,  4],
[0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0,  8,  2,  8,  2, 2,  2, 2, 0, 0,  2, 2, 10, 0, 2,  0, 0, 2,  2,  0,  2,  4,  0,  0, 6,  4,  4,  2,  4,  0],
[0,  4,  2, 0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  2, 2, 4, 6,  0, 0,  0, 0, 4,  0, 2, 6,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2, 0,  4,  0,  4,  0,  0],
[0,  0,  2, 0,  0, 2,  0,  0,  0,  6, 0,  0, 0, 4, 2,  0, 0,  0, 0, 0,  8, 0, 4,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0, 0,  2,  2,  0,  2,  2],
[0,  8,  4, 4,  0, 0, 12,  0,  6,  0, 6,  2, 0, 6, 4,  2, 2,  0, 4, 0,  0, 2, 2,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  2, 0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0,  0,  8, 0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  4, 0,  2, 6, 2, 0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 2,  0, 2, 0,  0,  2,  2,  0,  2,  0, 2,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0],
[0,  6, 10, 6,  6, 4,  0,  0,  0,  4, 0,  2, 0, 4, 4,  0, 0,  4, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0,  2,  0,  2,  0, 10,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  2,  0, 4,  0, 8,  2,  0,  2,  4, 0,  2, 2, 0, 0,  4, 2,  0, 2, 4,  2, 4, 4,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  4,  0, 0,  0, 0,  2, 10,  0,  2, 4,  0, 2, 0, 6,  4, 2,  0, 4, 0,  6, 2, 0,  2,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0, 0,  0,  6,  0,  2,  0],
[0,  0,  2, 2,  0, 4,  0,  0,  0,  0, 2,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 2,  0, 2, 0,  0, 2, 0,  2,  0,  0,  2,  2,  0, 0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  2]])
v = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1])
points = [v]
```

Comment: are you sure that the system `AA.x = v` has a (positive) solution? Even if I do the computation in Wolfram Mathematica ("symbolically", without loss of precision), I get some non-zero residual. Also, `Element[v, Simplex[Transpose[AA]]]` yields `False`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system you've posted above does not have an exact solution. So `np.dot(AA,x) - u)` will never converge to machine precision. In fact what your code is doing is finding the correct numerical approximation to the unique least squares solution of your system.

There are a number of ways to see why the system can't have a solution.  One way is to [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) that

> A linear system `Ax=b` is consistent if and only if the rank of `A` is equal to the rank of`[A|b]`, the matrix `A` augmented with `b` as a column.

You can estimate the ranks numerically as follows:

```
# reshape the RHS to a column so we can combine it with AA
b = points[0].reshape((36,1))

# append the column to form the augmented matrix
AA_b = np.hstack((AA, b))

print("AA rank: %d" % np.linalg.matrix_rank(AA))
print("[AA|b] rank: %d" % np.linalg.matrix_rank(AA_b))
```

This shows that the rank of `AA` is 35 but the rank of `[A|b]` is 36 and so the system can't have a solution.

You can also convince yourself this is true by putting the augmented matrix into reduced row echelon form.  I was able to do this quite quickly in wxMaxima and verify that the augmented matrix is RREF equivalent to the identity.  Doing so in sympy is also possible but seems to be quite slow:

```
AA_b.rref()
```

Comment: Thanks, I realised that my numerical error actually happened before (when choosing the matrix). Also the rank-argument is helpful, I forgot about it.